# SQL LEFT JOIN issue - wrong result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm here again with another question/problem. I know that topic's title may be like some others here, but I've noticed that they had another problems with that.

I have a problem with SQL LEFT JOIN. I'm using MySQL.

I want to have a table where TYPES would be for six months and calculations for one month (it might look strange, but I need it for some purposes).

I have two queries (I'll show query and output that it would be more specific).

First query is for six months:

```
SELECT objectsoort AS types, COUNT(objectsoort) AS total, prijs AS price, SUM(prijs)/ SUM(oppervlakte) AS meters
FROM `huislijn`
WHERE <clause statements>
GROUP BY objectsoort
```

And I get result like this:

[image: Six_months]

Second query is for one month:

```
SELECT objectsoort AS types1, COUNT(objectsoort) AS total1, AVG(prijs) AS price1, SUM(prijs)/ SUM(oppervlakte) AS meters1
FROM `huislijn`
WHERE <clause statements>
GROUP BY objectsoort
```

Then I get result like that:

[image: One month]

I want to make them as one so I'm using LEFT JOIN and get query like that:

```
SELECT a.types1, b.total1, b.price1, b.meters1
FROM (SELECT objectsoort AS types1
FROM  `huislijn` 
WHERE <clause statements> ) a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT objectsoort AS types12, COUNT( objectsoort ) AS total1, AVG( prijs ) AS price1, SUM( prijs ) / SUM( oppervlakte ) AS meters1
FROM `huislijn` 
WHERE <clause statements> ) b
ON a.types1 = b.types12
GROUP BY types1
```

BUT the result isn't what I've expected, because there should be some result near 'appartement' and 'woning' results isn't the same as in query for one month:

[image: both in one]

I repeat that it would be more clearly: I want types of six months and calculations for one month. In this case it means that results should be near 'appartement' and 'woning'.

So, I wanted to know, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks for your help and support.

Comment: OMG. I found where was the problem. THANKS!
Now it's all good. ;)

Comment: I meant in your third query, sorry. The joined table query is not the same as in your second query (missing the group by clause).

Comment: Please share your problem + solution with us. If appropriate, answer your own question and accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was asked to share solution, so here it is:

As **cularis** said, I was missed `GROUP BY objectsoort` in some places. There's the working query (I've changed it a bit, because working on it, but result is still the same):

```
SELECT a.types5, b.total5, b.price5, b.meters5, a.total, a.price, a.meters
FROM (
SELECT objectsoort AS types5, COUNT(objectsoort) AS total, prijs AS price, SUM(prijs)/SUM(oppervlakte) AS meters
FROM  `huislijn` 
WHERE <clause statements>
GROUP BY objectsoort ) a
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT objectsoort AS types15, COUNT(objectsoort) AS total5, AVG(prijs) AS price5, SUM(prijs)/SUM(oppervlakte) AS meters5
FROM `huislijn`
WHERE <clause statements>
GROUP BY objectsoort ) b
ON a.types5 = b.types15
GROUP BY types5
```

The result:

[image: result]

Thanks for **cularis**!